# error on preprocessing machine learning

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to apply preprocessing on the training data and I also tried rehsape function but that didn't work,I am getting the following errror:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [34, 12700]
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing,neighbors
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

df=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df.drop(['ID'],1,inplace=True)


X=np.array(df.drop(['label'],1))
y=np.array(df['label'])
print(X.shape)


X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
X=X.mean_


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)

clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1900,max_features='log2',max_depth=25)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

accuracy=clf.score(X_test,y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

Comment: what' the output of `X.shape` and `y.shape' ?

Comment: Is this error thrown during train_test_split or clf.fit()?

Comment: @VivekKumar the error is during clf.fit()

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar (12700,34)

Comment: Can you share the complete code and data?

Comment: @VivekKumar this is only the complete code

Comment: Please see the answer by @AkshayNevrekar. He has correctly pointed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)`
`X=X.mean_`

After this your X will only contain mean of each columns.

To transform the data use following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

scaler.fit(X)

X = scaler.transform(X)
```

For more details refer [scikit-doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)